# Substract multiple columns of dataframe based on condition with three columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, A and B. Each has the same dimensions and same columns. Lets say I want to substract both dataframes (dfB-dfA) if the values of the rows in the first three columns match. Below is an example.

dfA

[image]

dfB

[image]

NewDF

[image]

In the example above, it is easy because the columns are organised, however, in reality both dataframes are much bigger.

I tried with a for loop but it didn't work. I would much appreciate your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Not only images are useless for reproducibility (please provide text), but your example is also not demonstrating what would happen if the order was different or if some values had no match. Also you show duplicated combinations, show you match in order? In brief, your question needs improvement

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will update the question with more details about the approach followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is smart enough to take the indices into account. Just convert the columns you want to match into the index and perform your operation as NewDF = dfA-dfB

Answer (score 0):

Set the columns you want to match as index:

```
df_A = df_A.set_index(['contract', 'time', 'id'])
df_B = df_B.set_index(['contract', 'time', 'id'])
```

And then perform the operation between the `df_A` and `df_B`:

```
Newdf = df_A - df_B
```